# How can I fix my locale?

Tags: dpkg, kde, locale

I've tried to reconfigure my locale, but I keep getting the same error.

```
> yuri@Yuri-laptop:~$ sudo aptitude dist-upgrade
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = "en_US",
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "pt_BR.UTF-8",
        LC_MONETARY = "pt_BR.UTF-8",
        LC_CTYPE = "pt_BR.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "pt_BR.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "pt_BR.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "pt_BR.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "pt_BR.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "pt_BR.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "pt_BR.UTF-8",
        LC_PAPER = "pt_BR.UTF-8",
        LANG = "es_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
```